# How to get approval for an open graph action, used in an unpublished ios app?

Tags: ios, facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

As part of action submission, facebook requires a detailed step-by-step explanation of the required steps for publishing a  story on facebook. But since the IOS app is not yet published, its not available on App Store, and therefore facebook cannot test it.
Am i mising something here? Or is it necessary o have a working WEB app in order to publish an action?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question... Can you give Clarity about that..? I thought that you are integrated Facebook into your application but you are not able to test it whether it is working or not..? Is it right..?

Comment: to be able to use Open Graph, each application needs to define a set of actions to be used in the app ( such as reading, watching, etc). In order to be able to use an action, each application needs to submit the actions which its going to use to Facebook for review. more infor here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/ .

Comment: Now as part of this approval process, an step-by-step giude of application usage needs to be submitted (along with urls, test username and test passsword) , so people in facebook can take the steps and confirm that application needs to use that action. My question is that when The application is an ios app which is yet not published, how should we submit the step-by-step guide to facebook? given that facebook engineers wont be able to acess the app ( as its not on app store yet)

Comment: Out of bounds, I didn't worked on it unto now.. +1 for good question and please read the tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/  carefully which you have given, you will find the answer there itself. all the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but thorough explanation of the process that will result in your app registering a particular action should be sufficient, given that it fits their criteria including: "Simple," "Genuine" and "Non-abusive." Facebook simply needs to understand the why, how and when (how often) within the context of your app.

Most new actions for existing apps do not have the complete flow available until they are tested and released, so a basic understanding of how the action will be used within the context of the app should be all that is necessary for facebook approval.

I'm not sure how an app that is completely unavailable will be vetted, but any supporting online documentation (links to screenshots etc?) you could provide wouldn't hurt but shouldn't be necessary. Hopefully a thorough description of usage and context should be sufficient for them to make a determination so you can proceed with development.